# JSON Django dumpdata кириллица отображается некорректно

Tags: python-3.x, django, json

при дампе Json файлов кириллица отображается некорректно, подскажите что делать Json

python manage.py dumpdata products.productCategory > categories.Json

при работе с джанго для того что бы не восстанавливать все данные в SQLite3 вручную решил сделать дамп но кириллица в Json файлах отображается некорректно
(в других кодировках пробовал, не помогает)
[image: Json]

Comment: А чем вы смотрите `json` файл и какую кодировку при просмотре выставляете?

Comment: UTF -16 LE, vscode

Comment: Ну так попробуйте в других кодировках открыть )  `utf-8` хотя бы для начала

Comment: пробовал все ещё хуже становится

Comment: cp866 попробуйте. Вот этот декодер по вашим козябрам определяет, что была перекодировка cp866 -> cp1251 https://www.online-decoder.com/ru

Comment: И на будущее прилагайте данные текстом тоже, а не только картинкой

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Так в итоге нормально удалось прочитать или нет? )

Comment: да спасибо помогло